# Add months to IDate column of data.table in R

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

I have been using data.table for practically everything I was using data.frames for, as it is much, much faster on big in-memory data (several million rows). However, I'm not quite sure how to add days or months to an IDate column without using apply (which is very slow).

A minimal example:

```
dates = c("2003-01-01", "2003-02-01", "2003-03-01", "2003-06-01", "2003-12-01", 
          "2003-04-01", "2003-05-01", "2003-07-01", "2003-09-01", "2003-08-01")
dt = data.table(idate1=as.IDate(dates))
```

Now, let's say I want to create a column with dates 6 months ahead. Normally, for a single IDate, I would do this:

```
seq(dt$idate1[1],by="6 months",length=2)[2]
```

But this won't work as from= must be of length 1:

```
dt[,idate2:=seq(idate1,by="6 months",length=2)[2]]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing it to create column idate2 in dt?

Thanks a lot,
RR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `mondate` package and add the months to it and then convert it back to `iDate` class object.

```
require(mondate)
dt = data.table(idate1=as.IDate(dates))
dt[, idate2 := as.IDate(mondate(as.Date(idate1)) + 6)]

#         idate1     idate2
#  1: 2003-01-01 2003-07-01
#  2: 2003-02-01 2003-08-02
#  3: 2003-03-01 2003-09-01
#  4: 2003-06-01 2003-12-02
#  5: 2003-12-01 2004-06-01
#  6: 2003-04-01 2003-10-02
#  7: 2003-05-01 2003-11-01
#  8: 2003-07-01 2004-01-01
#  9: 2003-09-01 2004-03-02
# 10: 2003-08-01 2004-02-01
```

Although, I suppose that there might be other better solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll accept this mondate solution as it is almost x2 faster on a data.table with 1 million rows!

By the way, the dt$ inside can be removed, but remove the as.Date() will throw a warning.

Comment: @RenéR, alternatively you can directly use `as.IDate(mondate(dates) + 6)` to save you the `as.Date(.)` time.

Comment: Sure, thanks. In my real-life problem, though, my 1-million-row data.table is not constructed from a character vector!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lubridate`,

```
 library(lubridate)
 dt[, idate2 := as.IDate(idate1 %m+% months(6))]
        idate1     idate2
 1: 2003-01-01 2003-07-01
 2: 2003-02-01 2003-08-01
 3: 2003-03-01 2003-09-01
 4: 2003-06-01 2003-12-01
 5: 2003-12-01 2004-06-01
 6: 2003-04-01 2003-10-01
 7: 2003-05-01 2003-11-01
 8: 2003-07-01 2004-01-01
 9: 2003-09-01 2004-03-01
10: 2003-08-01 2004-02-01
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works very well! I accepted the solution with mondate since it was 2x faster than with lubridate on 1 million rows.

Comment: @Arun sorry it works for me. I am pretty sure that I have tested. Now I get the same result than you.